# Windows 10 updates VS UWP application build

Tags: msbuild, uwp

i have a UWP application under construction, where i have already finished one section, but before going further i decided to create a RELEASE build and see how it works on all of my machines.

And i have noticed this ( I have VS on all of my PCs, so i have built it in RELEASE on all PCs separately ):

1) Computer number one - Windows 10 Pro Activated Version 1607 OS Build 14393.447

2) Computer number two - Windows 10 Pro Activated Version 1607 OS Build 14393.447

3) computer number three - Windows 10 Pro not activated ( some lower version ).

On computer number three - build is successful but when app gets launched i get XamlParse exception. All other PCs work fine

**For information:**

Min version = 1024
Target version = 14393

**So my question is:** 
1) How can i test my application version on all Windows 10 build ( maybe microsoft created a tool for that )?
2) Any additional information, maybe someone has faced this already.

Comment: When you create a new UWP Project in VS, you define a Target Version and a Minimum Version (10240, 10586, 14393). Is it possible that your min. version is incompatible with your 3rd system? You can see these versions if you open your .csproj file with a texteditor.

Comment: @ThomasSchneiter I'm pretty sure that i have selected all versions, but let me check.

yeah, i have checked this, Min = 10240, Target = 14393

Btw, you can see and re-target in Project properties ( right click )

Comment: @ThomasSchneiter, Could it be that my Project has target = 14393, but my PC ( that which fails ) has lower version and screws up the build? Maybe if i create APPXBUNDLE on PC that do not have exceptions and installit on that failing one - all will work?

Comment: Yes it seems like you can use all API's from your Target Version but you have to check yourself if they work with your Min. Version.

Answer (score 0):

`XamlParseException` are raised when using XAML resources which are not part of the runtime.

There is not a lot of help from VS here, you will have to find the resource not available on the old version and remove/replace it. You can get more details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/version-adaptive-code#unsupported-scenarios).

Easily testing all the supported OS is not really supported yet:

> Visual Studio does not warn you about API compatibility. It is your
>   responsibility to test and ensure that your app performs as expected
>   on all OS versions between and including the Minimum and Target.

See this page for [details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/version-adaptive-code#configure-your-visual-studio-project).

Comment: Additional information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/updates-and-versions/choose-a-uwp-version)

Comment: @ThomasSchneiter but i'm almost 100% sure i haven't used any XAML controls that are Windows 10 specific and might have been added in new Windows builds. The only thing that might be - i have been editing Style copies and had one issue on that third PC that default themedResource that controls style uses by default is missing